# How to read multiple files, process and write separately using spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to read multiple files, `name*.txt` and process them.

For that I am using `MultiResourceItemReader`.

It is reading all files and process and write at one time only. I want to read multiple files seperately, process and write to them.

The code:

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<POJO> multiResourceItemReader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<POJO> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<POJO>();
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);

    Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:" + filePath );
    resourceItemReader.setResources(resources);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());
    return resourceItemReader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how the `MultiResourceItemReader` is designed to work. In your case, you can create a job instance per file.

There are many advantages of making one thing do one thing and do it well, one of them in your use case is restartability: If one of the jobs fail, you only restart the failed one.